# Run time error 1004 On Copying Data on the same workbook

Tags: vba, copy-paste

I'm trying to copy data from one sheet to another. 
But I'm getting an Run time error `1004 Application defined or object defined error`.

```
Sub copycells()
    Sheets("B").Select
    Range("A2:M299").Copy
    Sheets("A").Select
    Range("E20:Q317").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```

Is there any other way to do this.Thanks in advance

Comment: Which row you get the error on? This code works fine for me

Comment: On line 5 i.e Range("E20:Q317").Select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
Sub copycells()
    Sheets("A").Range("A2:M299").Copy
    Sheets("B").Range("E20:Q317").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```

Here is another method that doesn't even use "Activate"

```
Sub CopyCellsWithoutActivate()
    Sheets(1).Range("A2:M299").Copy
    Sheets(2).Range("E20:Q317").PasteSpecial (xlPasteAll)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Buddy. This works fine. May I know what was the problem with my code

Comment: As a general rule you want to avoid using "Select" and "Activate" whenever possible.

I udpated my original answer with a second version that is even a bit tidier than the first.

Oddly enough, although your code errored for me last night (and again this morning), now it is working fine. I still suggest using one of the several more elegant solutions which should b e less prone to error.